# Confused about higher potential at junction in real(practical) diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

My text book (*Microelectronics* by Sedra and Smith 7th edition) states:

> Hence a potential difference results across the depletion region, with the n side at a positive voltage relative to the p side, as shown in Fig. 3.9(b).

[image: Sedra and Smith Microelectronics 7th edition]

page 150

But again solving circuits with real diodes,
concept from below image works well.Since the junction potential opposes applied electric field during forward bias, it is quite logical to put "p" side at higher potential. But, my text book states that "n" side is at higher potential.

[image: ideal diode vs real diode characteristics]

Which side ("p" or "n") is at higher potential?

According to theory, it's the n side. According to the simple concept of overcoming barrier potential when a p-n junction is forward biased, it's the p side. For example, E1 has greater potential than E2 (assumed), and E1 has to overcome the electric field applied by E2.

[image: Example]

So I am confused.

While this question seems to be asked before, I made it more simple than before (editing previous question would hamper answers in them).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: updated now, sorry for delay

Comment: Don't distribute the book illegally on this website. Please remove the link on your Google Drive account. I have edited out the link for you but you still need to remove the source.

Comment: @SvenB I am sorry for that. I have turned off link sharing.

Comment: @Andyaka Please view my updated question.

Comment: And please re-read my original comment.

Comment: @Andyaka My question is "Which side(p or n) is at higher potential along with explanation in simpler terms?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in potential will *block* the current from flowing. If the N-side is at a higher voltage, then the current trying to flow from P to N will be stopped by the positive voltage barrier. Ie. positive charges going from P to N will not be able to, because they are driven away by the positive N-side (the other way with negative charges happens as well).

If you apply a more positive voltage to the P-side compared to the N-side, then the N-side will be *less* positive than before, and it is slightly easier for the positive charges to pass over this positive barrier, so the current increases.

[image: Wikipedia image]

The voltage source in the model you presented however has a different meaning. As the diode has an exponential characteristic, it is a pain to work with analytically. So they *approximate* the IV-curve with a model. But this is not necessarily a representation of the built-in potential, although it *can* (but not necessarily) be linked to it. The voltage source there is purely to *approximate* the black curve with the corresponding red curve.